# What game is John playing?

Tags: video-games, the-terminator-series, object-identification, terminator-2-judgment-day

In the arcade in *Terminator 2*, John is seen playing some sort of game with a big seat that rotates around. **What game is it?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

He's playing [After Burner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/After_Burner), as seen just before the T-1000 spots him.

[image: After Burner arcade game]

That particular unit appears to be the 1988 *[After Burner Deluxe Cabinet](https://www.arcade-museum.com/manuals-videogames/A/Afterburner%20Deluxe.pdf)*:

Comment: Wow, the manual says the thing weighs 946 pounds.

Comment: @Stormblessed - Tons of fun